# Array not updating correctly as "show array" class object is initialised in another class

Tags: java, arrays

I have a flat file with the name `cartList.txt`, and I have two classes with the names `GetCachedCartList.java` and `AddToShoppingList.java`.

I am using the class `GetCachedCartList.java` to get numbers (which are ids of products (I am working on aproject of a Shopping Cart)) from the flat file, these numbers are written in the file in form `num1#num2#num3#` etc., these numbers gets stored into the `int` array variable of this class.

As you can see, I have used '#' as the delimiter to distinguish between different numbers.

I am using the class `AddToShoppingList.java` to add the text `"num#"` to existing text present in the flat file.

The problem comes when I try to test these two classes, while the `GetCachedCartList.java` correctly outputs the numbers present in `cartList.txt` in its own main method, but when I use its object initialised in the main method of the `AddToShoppingList.java` after adding the piece of text like `"num#"`, its giving very unexpected results.The number `num` seems to have get added in the helping array many times instead of only one time, and the text `"num#"` also gets added in the flat file's text more than one time but less than it has in the array.

I suspected that this might be due to incorrect use of loops, but couldn't spot any error.

`cartList.txt`

> `2#3#`

`GetCachedCartList.java`

```java
package Resources.utils.queries;

/**
 *
 * @author Aditya
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetCachedCartList {
    private static ArrayList<String> StringcartProdIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static int[] cartProdIdList;

    public GetCachedCartList(){
        try{
            File cartListFile = new File("src/SessionData/productCachedData/cartList.txt");
            Scanner scann = new Scanner(cartListFile);
            scann.useDelimiter("#");
            while(scann.hasNext()){
                String s = scann.next();
                StringcartProdIdList.add(s); 
            }
            scann.close();

            cartProdIdList = new int[StringcartProdIdList.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < StringcartProdIdList.size(); i++){
                cartProdIdList[i] = Integer.parseInt(StringcartProdIdList.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the IDs of Items added in the Shopping Cart
     */
    public static int[] getCartProdIdList() {
        return cartProdIdList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GetCachedCartList g = new GetCachedCartList();
        System.out.println("Length: "+g.getCartProdIdList().length);
        for(int i: g.getCartProdIdList()){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

`AddToShoppingList.java`

```java
package Resources.utils.queries;

/**
 *
 * @author Aditya
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import Resources.utils.queries.GetCachedCartList;

public class AddToShoppingList {
    public AddToShoppingList(int pid){
        try{
            GetCachedCartList gCCl = new GetCachedCartList();
            int[] initialCartListArr = gCCl.getCartProdIdList();
            String initialCartList = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < initialCartListArr.length; i++){
                initialCartList += initialCartListArr[i] + "#";
            }
            File cartListFile = new File("src/SessionData/productCachedData/cartList.txt");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(cartListFile);
            writer.print("");
            writer.write(initialCartList);
            writer.write(pid+"#");
            writer.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GetCachedCartList gCCl1 = new GetCachedCartList();
        int[] initialCartListArr = gCCl1.getCartProdIdList();
        System.out.println("Initial cart list");
        for(int i = 0; i < initialCartListArr.length; i++){
            System.out.println(initialCartListArr.length+" : "+initialCartListArr[i]);
        }

        AddToShoppingList aTSL = new AddToShoppingList(9);

        System.out.println("Updated cart list");

        GetCachedCartList gCCl2 = new GetCachedCartList();
        int[] finalCartListArr = gCCl2.getCartProdIdList();
        for(int i = 0; i < finalCartListArr.length; i++){
            System.out.println(finalCartListArr.length+" : "+finalCartListArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The outputs the above codes, if you first run `GetCachedCartList.java`, and then `AddToShoppingList.java`, is:

`GetCachedCartList.java`

```
Length: 2
2
3
```

`AddToShoppingList.java`

```
Initial cart list
2 : 2
2 : 3
Updated cart list
9 : 2
9 : 3
9 : 2
9 : 3
9 : 2
9 : 3
9 : 2
9 : 3
9 : 9
```

And now the flat file have the text

```
2#3#2#3#9#
```

Where's is the mistake happening? Thanks~

Comment: How many times do you call `new GetCachedCartList()`? Does it match with the times of duplicated data? It does, because that constructor re-reads the file and adds its content to the list __again__.

Comment: each time  `new GetCachedCartList();` is executed a new set of the file is read and added to the same (`static`) array.... that design is a bit strange: 1) using `static`; 2) creating lots of instances

Comment: Yeah try to avoid using `static` class fields unless you _really_ know that you need it that way, which is probably unlikely.  It has its uses, but   this is definitely not one of them.  A `static` class field is the same across all instances of the object, so anything that affects it will affect all of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I correctly get your idea of the application. Sorry if not.
You have 0s because of  `String s = scann.next();` returns "`2, 3, \n`"
You have duplicates because of

```
AddToShoppingList.main {
    ...
    GetCachedCartList gCCl1 = new GetCachedCartList();
    ...
    GetCachedCartList gCCl2 = new GetCachedCartList();
}
```

I would suggest flowing code:

**Output**:

```
Error:null
Initial cart list
2 : 2
2 : 3
Error:null
Updated cart list
4 : 2
4 : 3
4 : 2
4 : 3
```

**Code**:

```
public class AddToShoppingList {
    public AddToShoppingList(int pid) {
        try {
            GetCachedCartList gCCl = new GetCachedCartList();
            List<Integer> initialCartListArr = gCCl.getCartProdIdList();
            String initialCartList = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < initialCartListArr.size(); i++) {
                initialCartList += initialCartListArr.get(i) + "#";
            }
            File cartListFile = new File("/home/ibondarenko/projects/demo/src/main/resources/cartList.txt");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(cartListFile);
            writer.print("");
            writer.write(initialCartList);
            writer.write(pid + "#");
            writer.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetCachedCartList gCCl1 = new GetCachedCartList();
        List<Integer> initialCartListArr = gCCl1.getCartProdIdList();
        System.out.println("Initial cart list");
        for (int i = 0; i < initialCartListArr.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(initialCartListArr.size() + " : " + initialCartListArr.get(i));
        }

        AddToShoppingList aTSL = new AddToShoppingList(9);

        System.out.println("Updated cart list");

//        GetCachedCartList gCCl2 = new GetCachedCartList();
        List<Integer> finalCartListArr = gCCl1.getCartProdIdList();
        for (int i = 0; i < finalCartListArr.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(finalCartListArr.size() + " : " + finalCartListArr.get(i));
        }
    }
}


public class GetCachedCartList {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> StringcartProdIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public GetCachedCartList() {
        try {
            File cartListFile = new File("/home/ibondarenko/projects/demo/src/main/resources/cartList.txt");
            Scanner scann = new Scanner(cartListFile);
            scann.useDelimiter("#");
            while (scann.hasNext()) {
                int s = scann.nextInt();
                StringcartProdIdList.add(s);
            }
            scann.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the IDs of Items added in the Shopping Cart
     */
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getCartProdIdList() {
        return StringcartProdIdList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetCachedCartList g = new GetCachedCartList();
        System.out.println("Length: " + StringcartProdIdList.size());
        for (int i : g.getCartProdIdList()) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your code first:

One class with logic to read `ids` from the file and retrieve `List<Integer>`:

```
public final class ReadCartProdIds {

    private final File file;

    public ReadCartProdIds(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public List<Integer> apply() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
            scan.useDelimiter("#");

            List<Integer> cartProdIds = new ArrayList<>();

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                cartProdIds.add(scan.nextInt());
            }

            return cartProdIds.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.unmodifiableList(cartProdIds);
        }
    }
}
```

Another one to add to this file new `pid` (you even do not have to reread existed file, just append new text to it):

```
public final class AddCarProdId {

    private final File file;

    public AddCarProdId(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void apply(int pid) throws IOException {
        Files.write(file.toPath(), (pid + "#").getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }

}
```

And finally your `main` program could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("d:/cartList.txt");
    printFile(file, "Initial cart list:");
    new AddCarProdId(file).apply(9);
    printFile(file, "Updated cart list");
}

private static void printFile(File file, String message) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(message);

    List<Integer> cartProdIds = new ReadCartProdIds(file).apply();
    cartProdIds.forEach(cartProdId -> System.out.println(cartProdIds.size() + " : " + cartProdId));
}
```